# Smalltalk: Writing output to a file

Tags: file-io, smalltalk

Usually with my output I am writing it to the Transcript with...

```
Transcript show:
```

How does one write the output to a file instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use a FileStream

See [this link describing FileStreams](http://live.exept.de/doc/online/english/overview/basicClasses/streams.html#FILESTREAM)

Excerpt below:

---

FileStream
FileStreams support all of ExternalStreams protocol. They can be created to read, write, readWrite or append from/to a file.
Creation:

```
* for reading:

      aStream := FileStream readonlyFileNamed:aFilenameString

* to read/write an existing file:

      aStream := FileStream oldFileNamed:aFilenameString

* to create a new file for writing:

      aStream := FileStream newFileNamed:aFilenameString
```

The above was the internal low level instance creation protocol, which is somewhat politically incorrect to use. For portability, please use the companion class Filename to create fileStreams:

```
* for reading:

      aStream := aFilenameString asFilename readStream

* to read/write an existing file:

      aStream := aFilenameString asFilename readWriteStream

* to create a new file for writing:

      aStream := aFilenameString asFilename writeStream

* to append to an existing file:

      aStream := aFilenameString asFilename appendingWriteStream
```

Answer (score 2):

```
| fileName aStream |

fileName := (Filename named: 'stream.st').

aStream := fileName readAppendStream.

aStream nextPutAll: 'What is the best class I have ever taken?'.

aStream cr.

aStream flush.

aStream nextPutAll: 'It is the VisualWorks Intro class!'.

aStream close.
```

Answer (score 0):

And then of course don't forget to handle the character encoding you want, if you're not writing binary or the default encoding. In Pharo/Squeak, set the converter to the needed TextConverter subclass.