# How to write txt file in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk

I try with this code:

```
f := 'testfile.txt' asFileReference.
f2 := f writeStream.
f2 nextPutAll: 'hello world'.
f2 close.
f content.
```

But I get this exception:

```
**FileDoesNotExistException**
```

Comment: Smalltalk: Writing output to a file
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055357/smalltalk-writing-output-to-a-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055357/smalltalk-writing-output-to-a-file)

Comment: Your code worked just fine for me (Pharo 6.1), except for one detail: the last message should be `contents`, with s.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia this was a problema xD, "contents"

Answer (score 4):

```
'testfile.txt' asFileReference 
    writeStreamDo: [ :stream | stream << 'Hello, World!' ].
```

This should work. But this is another way to express what you did before so I suspect some writing permission is wrong or something around that.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Estaban's response, one surprising behaviour of Pharo is that writeStreamDo overwrites the existing file, so if the existing file is longer than the new data, you end up with the new data and the tail end of the old data. Fortunately, there is a simple solution: you can simply include truncate. So a slightly "safer" version is:

```
    'testfile.txt' asFileReference 
writeStreamDo: [ :stream | stream truncate. stream << 'Hello, World!' ].
```